# Belt around two circles in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Given two circles I would like to create with geometry nodes a shape like a "BELT" that connects them like in the image:

[image: Diagram]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: hint: here is the formula to calculate it: http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Circles2/Circles2Tangent_.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it but it was quite complex in blender 3.1.
You can download the file here: https://we.tl/t-5QyaR4FuVd
I found i didn't need all the math when using a concex hull around two circles.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would be nice if you could provide a node screenshot which we could read…

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.